# Updating StarCount at first router entering in Vue3

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, vuejs3

The component starCount is loaded in as a component, it gets the uid passed from a prop, which gets passed from the prop. That is maybe the reason. It is not. The starcount can't react to a new value while at the same instance from onValue. That is the problem...

The parent component has such a node:

```
<ProfilePost v-if="author.post !== true" :username="`${author.username}`" :uid="`${author.uid}`" />
```

the child has such a grandchild

```
<StarCount :uid="`${props.uid}`" />
```

And it has this script

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center d-inline-block pt-2">
    <v-rating v-model="rating.count">
      <template v-slot:item="props">
        <v-icon
          :color="props.isFilled ? 'pink-lighten-3' : 'pink-lighten-5'"
          size="large"
          @click="props.onClick"
        >
          {{ props.isFilled ? 'mdi-star' : 'mdi-star' }}
        </v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-rating>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, watch } from 'vue'
import { getDatabase, increment, ref, update, onValue } from "firebase/database";
import { useCounterStore } from '@/stores/login'

const store = useCounterStore()
const props = defineProps(['uid'])
const db = getDatabase();

    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
    
        const db = getDatabase();
        const starCountRef = ref(db, 'users/' + props.uid + '/starCount');
        onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        store.StarCount = data
        updateStarCount(postElement, data);
        });
    
      }, 300);
    });

function addStarMin(uid, key) {
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

  const updates = {};
  updates[`users/${props.uid}/starCount`] = increment(-0.25);
  update(dbRef, updates);
}
function addStarMedMin(uid, key) {
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

  const updates = {};
  updates[`users/${props.uid}/starCount`] = increment(-.25);
  update(dbRef, updates);
}
function addStar(uid, key) {
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

  const updates = {};
  updates[`users/${props.uid}/starCount`] = increment(0);
  update(dbRef, updates);
}
function addStarMedMax(uid, key) {
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

  const updates = {};
  updates[`users/${props.uid}/starCount`] = increment(0.025);
  update(dbRef, updates);
}
function addStarMax(uid, key) {
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

  const updates = {};
  updates[`users/${props.uid}/starCount`] = increment(.25);
  update(dbRef, updates);
}
const rating = reactive({ count: store.StarCount })
watch(
  () => rating.count,
  () => {
    // fires only when state.someObject is replaced
    if (rating.count > 5) {
        rating.count = 5
    }
    if (rating.count == 1)
    addStarMin();
    if (rating.count == 2)
    addStarMedMin();
    if (rating.count == 3)
    addStar();
    if (rating.count == 4)
    addStarMedMax();
    if (rating.count == 5)
    addStarMax();
  }
)
</script>
```

The starCount does not update at first visit

Btw. i'm using the Vuetify 3.0.0.beta.0

Comment: Your question should show the code (a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)) that doesn't work the way you expect. Without that, it's highly unlikely that you'll get good feedback on what's wrong and how to fix it.